# Align thead with td in tbody

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have trouble aligning the `thead` with the `td` in `tbody`. I've tried adjusting the `thead` using **display: table-header-group;**.  I also found out from here: [Why isn't padding applied to table elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595932/why-isnt-padding-applied-to-table-elements), that padding does not work on 'table-header-group'. Thus when I tried providing `padding-left` to my `th` via **CSS**, nothing is happening. I've also tried using more `<th></th>` before my `<th>Quantity</th> <th>Amount</th> <th>Total</th>` so that 'more space' is added. However, I am still not able to align the thead with my content in tbody.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? If possible, please also let me know if I am not doing things right. Any help is much appreciated. 
Thank you!

Screenshot and code is provided below:
[thead is too left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty4Jw.png)

Here is my code:

```
<div class="table-responsive col-lg-12 " ng-show="ngCart.getTotalItems() > 0">
<table class="table-responsive table-striped ngCart cart summaryTable " >
    <thead >
    <tr cellpadding="10">
      <th>Item</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr ng-show="ngCart.getTax()">
   <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Tax ({{ ngCart.getTaxRate() }}%):</td>
        <td>{{ ngCart.getTax() | currency }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="ngCart.getShipping()">
     <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Shipping:</td>
        <td>{{ ngCart.getShipping() | currency }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total:</td>
        <td>{{ ngCart.totalCost() | currency }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in ngCart.getCart().items track by $index">

        <td>{{ item.getName() }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.getQuantity() | number }}</td>

        <td>{{ item.getPrice() | currency}}</td>
        <td>{{ item.getTotal() | currency }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

</table></div>
```

Comment: Your issue is css related. Without a demo that replicates it that we can inspect  in browser dev tools there isn't much anyone here can do. Use your dev tools to inspect each element and see what actual rules apply to it. You can also live edit them to try adjustments. Then when you find something that fixes it add an over ride css rule

Comment: If possible create  a simple html demo along with all your css in  plunker

Comment: The only css that I used is 'summaryTable' which contains 'width: 100%;'  to make the table responsive on mobile. Other classes are provided by the plugin itself. 
However, good news! My friend suggested applying a css that contains 'text-align: center;' to all the th tags, and it worked!
Thanks again to everyone who replied :)

Answer (score 1):

what you did was correct. all you need is to center the text alignment of your thead. or just align the tbody left.

Comment: Yes, I did that after and it worked. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: great!. happy coding.. @zwxzwx